# Strange behaviour of .test() in jquery for testing regular expressions

Tags: jquery, regex

I don't know why when I test a regex alone, for example here: http://jconsole.com/, that regex works perfectly, while if I put that regex in my JQuery code, it fails.

Here an example of my JQuery code:

```
var $fullName = $("input[name='txtFullName']");
var $fullNameRegex = /^(?:([a-zA-Z]{2,4}\.){0,1} ?([a-zA-Z]{2,24})) ([a-zA-Z]{1,1}\. ){0,1}([a-zA-Z]{2,24} ){0,2}([A-Za-z']{2,24})((?:, ([a-zA-Z]{2,5}\.?)){0,4}?)$/img;

if($fullNameRegex.test($fullName) == false) 
{
    //display an error div and other things
    return false;
}
```

I'm really going mad because I don't understand why is still failing with correct inputs.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: please show us how you initialise `$myregex` and `$input`.

Comment: nb: `.test()` is a standard JS function, nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: What does "failling" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, which one? Or does it not produce the results you expect?

Comment: @FelixKling, yes it doesn't produce the results that I'm expecting, while when i test it on jconsole.com it produces the results I'm expecting.

Answer (score 3):

You can't test a jQuery collection with a regex - you need to compare its `.val()`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! Now I've updated my code, adding .val() and it works perfectly. Now I feel quite stupid, because it was really easy... :)